# PHP CSV Export script, Struggling a bit with the logic

Tags: php, csv, php-5.3

Ok I have this CSV export script which is working but I want to add in another query which will get the order items of each individual order.

And put the order items for each order in the final cell of each row like so:

Order_Items:
Item1, items2, item3 etc...

I have the query for the order items but Im not sure how to fit it in with the complex while and for each loops.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
  <?php
  include "../Config/db.config.php";;

 // Make a MySQL Connection
 $link =  mysql_connect(EZSQL_DB_HOST, EZSQL_DB_USER, EZSQL_DB_PASSWORD);

 if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

if (!mysql_select_db(EZSQL_DB_NAME, $link)) {
   echo 'Could not select database';
  exit;
}

 $select = "SELECT intOrderID as Order_ID, strPaymentMethod as Payment_Method, strPaymentRef as Payment_Ref, strPaymentStatus as Payment_Status,
       dtmDate as Date, curPaymentAmount as Net_Price, curShippingFee as Shipping_Fee FROM tbl_mod_ShopOrders";

$items = "SELECT intProductID, strProductTitle, curPrice, intQty FROM tbl_mod_ShopOrderItems WHERE intOrderID = $value";


$export = mysql_query ($select) or die ( "Sql error : ". mysql_error() );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
   $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . ",";  
}

$header .= 'Order_Items'; // Added additional cell title. 

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
   $line = '';
foreach( $row as $value )
{                                            
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
    {
        $value = ",";
    }
    else
    {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . ",";
    }
    $line .= $value;
}
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
 }
    $data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

 if ( $data == "" )
 {
     $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

 header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Customer_export.csv");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");
 print "$header\n$data";
 exit;
```

Comment: CSV is not very well suited to one-to-many data relationships like you have here. It is fairly easy to get this data from the database, not so easy to put it into CSV format. In order to be correct CSV, each row should have an identical number of columns, so you need to add one final column which contains the data for *all* the order items - what if an order has 100 items? The key point here is *what are you going to do with the CSV file?* - if it needs to be machine readable you could make the last column (for example) JSON - if you want to view it in Excel, it will be much more difficult...

Comment: Also, you should use [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) for outputing CSV data. If you want to echo it directly without creating a temp file, you can always write it to a file pointer you create with `php://temp` or (better) `php://output`

Comment: It is unlikely to ever be 100 items, only maybe 4 or 5 max, its just to be human readable so a final column that contains the data for all the order items is exactly what i am trying to do

Comment: Well your query that fetches the items selects multiple columns - how would you display that in a human readable way? Can you add some example data as it is stored in MySQL, and how you would like the CSV output to look?

Comment: I would like the csv file to have another column added called order_items then in this column just have strProductTitle, curPrice, intQty for each item separated with a carriage return or something in the column(if possible) but I do see what you mean about it not being human readable.

Comment: ach forget it. Its just not worth it. Your right DaveRandom

Comment: Wait a second, I nearly have an answer ready...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% on the query here, it may need tweaking to get exactly what you want. I feel that it is the query that matters here, you can get MySQL to do most of the grunt work for you. I have used the `fputcsv()` approach for formatting the data here as it will produce the best results. I am also loathed to use `or die()` but since it is the way you handle errors in the above code, it is what I have done here.

Hopefully this will give you a decent starting point:

```
<?php

  // Make a MySQL Connection
  include "../Config/db.config.php";;
  $link = mysql_connect(EZSQL_DB_HOST, EZSQL_DB_USER, EZSQL_DB_PASSWORD)) or die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db(EZSQL_DB_NAME, $link)) or die('Could not select database: '.mysql_error($link));

  // Get data from database
  $query = "
    SELECT
      `o`.`intOrderID` AS 'Order_ID',
      `o`.`strPaymentMethod` AS 'Payment_Method',
      `o`.`strPaymentRef` AS 'Payment_Ref',
      `o`.`strPaymentStatus` AS 'Payment_Status',
      `o`.`dtmDate` AS 'Date',
      `o`.`curPaymentAmount` AS 'Net_Price',
      `o`.`curShippingFee` AS 'Shipping_Fee',
      `i`.`Order_Items`
    FROM `tbl_mod_ShopOrders` `o`
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
        `intOrderID`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('ID=', `intProductID`, '; Title=', `strProductTitle`, '; Price=', `curPrice`, '; Qty=', `intQty`) SEPARATOR '\\n') AS 'Order_Items'
      FROM `tbl_mod_ShopOrderItems`
      GROUP BY `intOrderID`
    ) `i` ON `o`.`intOrderID` = `i`.`intOrderID`
  ";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query error: ".mysql_error($link));

  // Check there were some results
  mysql_num_rows($result) or die('No data to output');

  // Open fake file pointer to output buffer
  $outFp = fopen('php://output', 'w') or die('Unable to open file pointer for output buffer');

  // Send headers for CSV download
  header("Content-Type: text/csv");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Customer_export.csv");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

  // Output columns headers and first row
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  fputcsv($outFp, array_keys($row));
  fputcsv($outFp, $row);

  // Output rest of data...
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    fputcsv($outFp, $row);
  }

  // ...and we're done.
  exit;
```

N.B. the `LEFT JOIN` is arguably unnecessary, since you would never have an order with no items on it, but it's as well to be safe.